# JQuery: fadeIn does not work properly. Content is only a short time visible

Tags: jquery

i use JQuery to fadeIn my content like this:

```
.content {
display:none;
}

$('.content').fadeIn(500);
```

But the .content is only visible a short time, it just "flickers" for a sec. It seems that the css is overruling the JQuery command.

Does anybody know that and how can i solve it?

Edit:
I'm only using the code from above. Only difference is, that i have a div .container_inside and the div .content is loaded into the .container_inside with $.load(). After the load i do $('.content').fadeIn(500). Could it be, that the content div is loaded and the JQuery command after it can't "find" .content? I don't have a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `delay` [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ncqgf/3/)

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

​
*Css*

```
.content {
    display:none;
}​
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="content">
    Some text blah blah blah...
</div>​
```

Comment: There really shouldn't be a need to use delay unless there's something else causing the OP's fadeIn() call to not work properly.

Comment: That's true but the OP didn't mention much details in his question.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem is. Sure, the fiddle works fine. In my opinion my problem has eventually to do with other js scripts which may be interfering? I thought anybody knows the issue...

Comment: @Torben-If you post your code you're using other than this would be much helpful to get the problem resolved.

Comment: @Torben, we can't see your page... how are we supposed to know your issue?

Comment: I'm only using the code from above. Only difference is, that i have a div .container_inside and the div .content is loaded into the .container_inside with $.load(). After the load i do $('.content').fadeIn(500). Could it be, that the content div is loaded and the JQuery command after it can't "find" .content?

Comment: Did you just write `load(somefile); $(content).fadeIn();` or did you place the fade function in the `load()` callback function ??

Comment: @Torben, it would be great if you edited your question to include that extra information.

Comment: No, i haven't any callback function. I just write it as u wrote it. How can i use a callback?

Comment: @Torben Can you say what have you done?

Comment: sure: $('.container_inside').load('path', function() {
   $('.content').fadeIn(500);  
  });

Comment: Yes. that's a callback function, it executes the fadeIn when the content is actually in the page. Do it the other way, and the fadeIn will execute before the content is available, that is the nature of asynchronous calls, aka Ajax.